# UITableView with huge(probably 1million entries)data in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, core-data

I am developing an application which requires loading of more than 1 million entries through infinite scrolling in a tableview. Each time request will be sent for 1000 entries and once data is downloaded and parsed through JSON library the table is reloaded. I have implemented this through CoreData with "setFetchBatchSize = 1000".

```
StreamModal *modal = [[StreamModal alloc]init];
              StreamModal *modal = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"StreamModal" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
                 if([self isNotNull:[streamDataDict objectForKey:@"_id"]])
                     modal.stream_id               = [streamDataDict objectForKey:@"_id"];

-(void)reloaData{
@try {
    NSError *error;
    if (![[self fetchedResultsController] performFetch:&error]) {
        // Update to handle the error appropriately.
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        exit(-1);  // Fail
    }
    NSLog(@"ferchresults count %d",[[_fetchedResultsController fetchedObjects]count]);
}
@catch (NSException *exception) {
    NSLog(@"exception raised in reloadData in streamViewController class %@",exception);
}
@finally {

}
}


- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController {

if (_fetchedResultsController != nil) {
    return _fetchedResultsController;
}

NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"StreamModal" inManagedObjectContext:appDelegate.managedObjectContext];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

NSSortDescriptor *sort = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"date" ascending:NO];
[fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sort]];

[fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:1000];
//[fetchRequest setFetchLimit:2000];

NSFetchedResultsController *theFetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:appDelegate.managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:nil];
self.fetchedResultsController = theFetchedResultsController;
_fetchedResultsController.delegate = self;

fetchRequest = nil;
theFetchedResultsController = nil;

return _fetchedResultsController;    

}
```

Here is the code i am using, when ever connectionfinishedloading data i am populating the data into NSManagedObject Class(StreamModal) and then calling reload data.Here the problem is the app is getting memory exceptions after i loaded 12000 entries in table and getting crashed. how can i load all entries without memory exception. i am new to CoreData concepts and have read the core data concepts through developer guide, but i didn't find any info related to memory handling. Please help me.

Comment: How long does it _take_ to scroll one million rows with your thumb on an iphone screen? This seems ridiculous.

Comment: OMG. Who is client ? I would love to meet him/her? 1 million entries?

Comment: as per my knowledge i can say better to download the parts of data every time user scrolls or for any other event,otherwise the memory in the Device is limited so it will not allow tht much data to load at a time....

Comment: Provide an index and drill down. Millions of rows in a single table on a 4 inch screen is ludicrous.

Comment: What's with the Exception handlers wrapping NSError?

Comment: Practically we don't have 1 million, but as a load test we are doing it. and i am getting the memory exception after loading 12000 entries it self.

Comment: @Abizern: Getting Memroy Warning Level 1 and Level 2 and app is getting crashed.

Comment: @Lak in iphone: i am not loading at a time, each time i am loading 1000 entries and these 1000 will be added to previous results.

Answer (score 1):

I hope you are using ARC? Because you're not releasing any initalized objects. (If not this is your answer.)

But anyway: Have you tried to use Instruments to see, which objects are increasing the memory footprint at most? That would be a good starting point.

Comment: Thanks iaydee3, Yes i have checked with instruments and as i observed the live bytes are increasing in between 15 to 17MB when downloading 5000 entries(each time only 1000) and as page count increasing the memory size also increasing(but each time i am downloading 1000 entries only and saving them using coredata)and when downloading and reloading of table is done live bytes are falling back to 3.0MB. I am not able to figure it out why the live bytes are keep on increasing, i thought it might be because of reloading the table with 12000 entries.

Answer (score 0):

shiva inturi,

First, I want to echo other comments that working with a single table view of a million items is really a bad user experience.

To your question:

What are you doing when the memory warning comes?

At minimum, you should be going through the objects array and trim the object graph. This is done with `-refreshObject:mergeChanges:`. You should also take care to not traverse your array very far. I would start from your visible objects and work both backwards and forwards until you start hitting faulted objects, by testing with `-isFault`.

Andrew